# vue-cli - updating compile script

Tags: vue.js

Sorry if this is more of a Node or Webpack question than a Vue or vue-cli one, but I'm using vue-cli and I'd like to change something in the way it operates and am not quite sure where to look. I used vue-cli with the Webpack template to create two Vue.js projects, a number of months apart. Clearly at the time of the second project, the version of some component or script had been updated. Now, when I make a change to a watched file and the compiler kicks in and gives me a message like 'DONE Compiled successfully in 875ms', it has a timestamp next to it telling me when the compile was done. The earlier project is missing this timestamp and I'd like to be able to get it to show it, because for some reason I've not been able to determine, occasionally the compiler does not seem to pick up the fact that a change has occurred, and I end up trying to work out why my latest change isn't working, only to discover that it hasn't actually been compiled yet. If it showed the timestamp I'd be able to see instantly whether or not I'm up to date.

Comment: As a summery, you want to make sure  webpack hot reloaded based on time stamp change right ? Or is it build which you execute by typing npm run build

Comment: Yes, the hot reloading - npm run dev